# Legendre test re First Variation

Tags: calculus-of-variations

The Legendre test (as mentioned in *An Introduction to the Calculus of Variations* by Charles Fox, requires that the sign of $\partial^2 F \over\partial y'^2$ is constant throughout the range of integration then (provided that the other 2 conditions are satisfied, the functional of the stationary path is max or min depending on the sign of $\partial^2 F \over\partial y'^2$. What if $\partial^2 F \over\partial y'^2$ vanishes at some points but have the same sign for all others in the range?

***Added:*** The Legendre test:
If 1) Euler's equation is satisfied, 2) the range of integration is sufficiently small, 3) sign of $\partial^2 F \over\partial y'^2$ is constant on range of integration Then the functinal of the stationary path is max or min depending on the sign of $\partial^2 F \over\partial y'^2$.

Thanks.